# Is there a way to split an RDD by rows?

Tags: java, string, apache-spark, split, rdd

i have a bunch of Data with 20000 rows in a JavaRDD. Now i want to save several files with exact the same size (like 70 rows per file).

I tried it with the code below, but because it is not exactly dividable some data sets consist of 69, 70 or 71 rows. The struggle is I need all with the same size except the last record (it can have less).

Help is appreciated!!! Thanks in advance guys!

myString.repartition(286).saveAsTextFile(outputPath);

Comment: That's not exactly how Spark works. Can I ask, why it is important to have the exact same number of rows in each file??

Comment: rdd.coalesce(((rdd.count()/70).toInt)).saveAsTextFile("directory_where_") try this coalesce then saveAsTextFile

Comment: @rohitprakash that did not work for me. my 16353 rows where only divided into two files with 8242 and 8111 rows.
trainDataFeatures.coalesce((int)(trainDataFeatures.count()/70)).saveAsTextFile(outputPathTrainFeatures);

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt because i want to put my data into an SequenceRecordReader for fitting a machine learning model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately a Scala answer, but it works.

First define a custom partitioner:

```
class IndexPartitioner[V](n_per_part: Int, rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_ <: Product2[Long, V]], do_cache: Boolean = true) extends org.apache.spark.Partitioner {

    val max = {
        if (do_cache) rdd.cache()
        rdd.map(_._1).max
    }

    override def numPartitions: Int = math.ceil(max.toDouble/n_per_part).toInt
    override def getPartition(key: Any): Int = key match {
        case k:Long => (k/n_per_part).toInt
        case _ => (key.hashCode/n_per_part).toInt
    }
}
```

Create an RDD of random strings and index it:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array.tabulate(1000)(_ => scala.util.Random.alphanumeric.filter(_.isLetter).take(5).mkString))  
val rdd_idx = rdd.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)
```

Create the partitioner and apply it:

```
val partitioner = new IndexPartitioner(70, rdd_idx)
val rdd_part = rdd_idx.partitionBy(partitioner).values
```

Check partition sizes:

```
rdd_part
  .mapPartitionsWithIndex{case (i,rows) => Iterator((i,rows.size))}
  .toDF("partition_number","number_of_records")
  .show

/**
+----------------+-----------------+
|               0|               70|
|               1|               70|
|               2|               70|
|               3|               70|
|               4|               70|
|               5|               70|
|               6|               70|
|               7|               70|
|               8|               70|
|               9|               70|
|              10|               70|
|              11|               70|
|              12|               70|
|              13|               70|
|              14|               20|
+----------------+-----------------+
*/
```

One file for each partition:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
rdd_part.toDF.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("/tmp/idx_part_test/")
```

(+1 for "_SUCCESS")

```
XXX$ ls /tmp/idx_part_test/ | wc -l
16
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filterByRange do something like (pseudo code):

```
for i = 0; i < javaRDD.size ; i+= 70
    val tempRDD = javaRDD.filterByRange(i,i+70).repartition(1)
    tempRDD.saveAsTextFile(outputPath + i.toString());
```

Comment: I was in the process of writing up my own answer, but this is cleaner :)

Comment: there is no filterByRange for JavaRDD<String> . 

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html

What am I doing wrong?